# Apache Camel - Listening to route events like completion of a route

Tags: apache-camel

I’m stuck at one particular requirement in camel , I’m processing a set of files and when any exception occurs i send a message to an exception queue , and from the exception queue im sending an email about the failure , the functionality is working fine but I end up sending many mails, like if 10 files fail im sending 10 emails, is there a way to send only one mail , like I would want to wait for the entire route to finish , then go look the exception queue and send a single mail stating what has failed (by processing the exception queue )

I'm open for suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

I had to do this scenario once (inversed though - mail on success). I had a handy MySQL database configured and ready, so I just added each event from the queue to the database. Then once every now and then, extracted all info (and deleted it)- simply `select * from events; delete from events;` from the database and created a mail.

You could process the error queue with the aggregator pattern, it is very nice for these tasks. http://camel.apache.org/aggregate-example.html . You still need to know WHEN the aggregator should fire off a message. If you can, trigger a "finish, send mail" event such as in the example in the link above.

The most simple way would be to time schedule these mail notifications. Take a look at: http://camel.apache.org/simplescheduledroutepolicy.html . You can set it to run your route for some good choice of time, then when it fires off, you set the aggreator to complete upon timeout, and make the timeout good enough to empty any reasonable queue size of errors, but not too large.

At least that's my suggestions to your issue

Comment: Thanks Petter , i did look into the options you had listed .I did a hack and used the current date as an identifier in the header and  ended up using an idempotent consumer on the exception endpoint.so this enables me from sending only one mail a day for any exception that happens in that day ,since the content of the mail is not dynamic (just directs the admin to look at the failed folder) this seems to work for me , but in the long run i would like to implement using the suggestions listed above